# using recently created attributes in pandas dataframe to create new attribute

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, dplyr

I'm looking for the equivalent of R's mutate, which allows you to reference defined variables immediately after creating them *within the same mutate call*.

```
new_df <- old_df %>%
    mutate(new_col = ifelse(something, 0, 1),
           newer_col = ifelse(new_col == 0, 'yay', 'nay'))
```

Looking for the equivalent in python pandas.

if I create the following dataframe, I was wondering if there is a way to use `.assign` to do the same thing?

```
dic = {'names': ['jeff', 'alice', 'steph', 'john'],
       'numbers':[4, 6, 5, 7]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

df = df.assign(less_than_6 = np.where(df.numbers < 6, 100, 0),
               pass_fail = np.where(df.less_than_6 == 100, 'pass', 'fail'))
```

The alternative I can think of is..

```
df['less_than_6'] = np.where(df.numbers < 6, 100, 0)
df['pass_fail'] = np.where(df.less_than_6 == 100, 'pass', 'fail')
```

but was wondering if there is a way to do it in the same call?

Comment: doesn't work. I get the same `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'less_than_6'` as I got before. thank you for the try though!

Comment: Add it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dict in `assign`

```
df.assign(**{'less_than_6' :lambda x : np.where(x['numbers'] < 6, 100, 0)}).assign(**{'pass_fail':lambda x : np.where(x['less_than_6'] == 100, 'pass', 'fail')})                                                            
Out[202]: 
   names  numbers  less_than_6 pass_fail
0   jeff        4          100      pass
1  alice        6            0      fail
2  steph        5          100      pass
3   john        7            0      fail
```

Comment: awesome, thank you. Can you explain what `**` is doing?

Comment: @MattW. ** is for kwargs, yo ucan check the link https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean